# No se pudo encontrar el driver

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pdo

Estoy aprendiendo a usar Laravel 5.6.

Tenía instalado AppServ con versión de PHP 5.6 y para los requerimientos de Laravel es tener una versión igual o mayor a 7.1.3, desinstale AppServ y descargue Xampp, que tiene la versión más actual de PHP. Además de eso, instale Laravel a través de Composer y hasta ahí todo bien.

El problema viene cuando deseo hacer migraciones con este comando:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Responde que el driver no existe pero realmente si existe, ya que ya lo verifique en mi phpinfo, mi php.ini y la ubicación de los modulos en Xampp con la ruta que hay en php.ini, y todo encaja, además de que ejecute una función para saber si existe el modulo.

El error en concreto es:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
could not find driver: (SQL select * from information_schema.tables 
where tables_schema = appmarket and table_name = migrations)
```

¿Alguna otra idea?

Comment: con que gestor de bases de datos tratas de conectarte

Comment: Hola, Alfredo. Trato de conectarme con MySQL y MariaDB

Comment: por favor verifica que en tu archivo .env tengas tanto el puerto 3306 así como el driver mysql, y despues haz el comando composer dump autoload, vuelve a tratar y me comentas

Comment: Deja lo intento y te comento. Si mi MySQL no tiene contraseña, ¿Debo de poner en .env la password como null? ¿O solo la dejo vacia?

Comment: no debes colocar nada, me comentas como te fue

Comment: Utiliza Homestead o Docker, evitas este tipo de inconvenientes por trabajar directamente en tu máquina.

Comment: ¿Homestead se tiene que instalar antes de instalar laravel? La verdad que ando perdido xD

Comment: @AlfredoPaz Me sigue apareciendo el mismo error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No pude encontrar la solución para Xampp ni AppServ, por lo que seguí el consejo de Shaz e instale Homestead.

Al descargar Homestead todo perfecto hasta que utilice el comando `vagrant up` y me saltaba un error. El problema es que vagrant [no puede ejecutar esa ruta si tiene caracteres especiales](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/4966) (esto incluye el nombre de usuario con el que inicias sesión en tu computadora también).

Después de eso, cuando intente ejecutar `php artisan migrate`, me salto el siguiente error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
[PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused.
```

El problema era que Homestead me creo mi archivo `.env` y el DB_HOST que traía por defecto era el `127.0.0.1`, cuando en realidad debio haber sido `192.168.10.10` o el IP que hayas puesto en tu archivo `Homestead.yaml`.

Con eso pude hacer las migraciones y no se me ha presentado ningún problema.

Answer (score 0):

En tu archivo .env debes tener unos valores como:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Asegura que correspondan con tu base de datos.

Si lo tienes bien aquí, pasa a revisar en *config/database.php*

Busca el código que configure para mysql. Es algo como:

```
'mysql' => [
    'read' => [
        'host' => '192.168.1.1',
    ],
    'write' => [
        'host' => '196.168.1.2'
    ],
    'sticky'    => true,
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'database'  => 'database',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
],
```

Este ejemplo lo saqué de la [doc oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database) donde puedes guiarte también para configurar tu conexión.

También es recomendable setear los valores de configuración de acuerdo a tu archivo .env. Para eso puedes usar el [helper env()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-env). Por ejemplo, para no colocar la contraseña de la DB directamente en el código (ya que cualquiera que acceda al código tendrá las credenciales), puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'my_default_password'),
```

Lo que hará es buscar en el archivo .env el valor de DB_PASSWORD y usarlo. Si no lo encuentra, usará el valor del segundo parámetro como default.

No estoy seguro si en 5.6 también puedes colocar la DB por default usando

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
```

Podrías intentarlo también.

Obivamente antes de ejecutar el comando, asegúrate que la DB esté activa con XAMPP (ya que es lo que estás usando).

Con esto deberías poder correr tus migraciones.